# What does tomcat's ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener do exactly?

Tags: java, thread-local, thread-local-storage

The documentation for `org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener` says

> A `LifecycleListener` that triggers the renewal of threads in Executor
>   pools when a `Context` is being stopped to avoid thread-local related
>   memory leaks.

How does it exactly prevent `ThreadLocal` Memory leaks? Does it explicitly call `ThreadLocal`'s `remove()` method when the context is stopped ?

As far as I know, `ThreadLocal` is implemented as a hash map. The map keys are references to the `ThreadLocal` instances themselves. The map values are the thread local values.

Comment: Have you tried reading the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/7.0.14/org/apache/catalina/core/ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener.java)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First some clarification. `ThreadLocal` leak happens when you place some custom class in `ThreadLocal` inside your application and you undeploy/redeploy that application without clearing `ThreadLocal` first. When this happens, thread still holds a reference to your class, which holds a reference to `ClassLoader`, which in turns holds references to all other classes loaded by your (already undeployed) web application.

And the thread still holds a reference to your object because `ThreadLocal` values are actually stored *inside* thread. Failing to clear `ThreadLocal` means that this particular value will be held by `Thread` object as long as it's running.

Now back to your question - if you forget to remove some `ThreadLocal` it will be referenced by pool threads forever. This is what Tomcat is trying to prevent - shutting down and creating new threads if suspecting leak. It's invisible to web applications, but when you stop pool thread and replace it with new one, the old one becomes last object referencing your class, class loader and all other stuff. Finally your `ThreadLocal` value is eligible for GC.

Comment: Thanks for the great response Tomasz. I am just curious to know how exactly does tomcat "suspect leak" ?
Does it monitor the idle time of thread ? Or monitors if the thread has responded, thrown exception etc ?

Comment: @Sumit: unfortunately that I don't know. But I *suspect* that it has to examine all its thread pools and `ThreadLocal`s during undeployment.